# Compared to mod_wsgi, how does mod_python "work"?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, mod-python

It seems most of the blog posts the web relating to mod_python & mod_wsgi concentrate on telling me how mod_wsgi is better and what a WSGI application looks like. This is fine, but what I'd really want to know -- to have complete knowledge of the subject -- is:

How do they differ in running a script?

With CGI the server simply sets up the environment and runs a simple .py. WSGI wraps the application in an object, but the concept is still pretty much the same: run a .py file.

How does mod_python do it?

I'm also really interested in learning how anything mod_ works, so, really, feel free to point me to anything interesting on the subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the official mod_python documentation, namely:

- [So what exactly does mod_python do?](http://modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.3.1/doc-html/tut-what-it-do.html)
- [Multiple interpreters](http://modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.3.1/doc-html/pyapi-interps.html)

In practice, please note that there *usually* is no need to run Apache at all when working with python and web as there are many, many ways of serving the pages from python directly

Standard library:

- [http.server](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server.html)
- [wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref#module-wsgiref.simple_server)

External web servers:

- [Green Unicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)
- [Twisted web](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html)
- ...and many others

External Web frameworks:

- [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/)
- [WerkZeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)
- [numerous others](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Comment: "no need to run Apache at all" Although Apache can be used as a proxy in front of these servers. Useful to serve multiple sites with a single server.

Comment: AFAIK, running multiple sites on a single server can also be achieved by most if not all of the pure python alternatives. E.g http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/VirtualHosts

Comment: Whether one can run multiple sites on a single server depends on the framework/application being run. Django for example cannot run multiple sites with distinct code bases in the same process unless the hosting mechanism supports use of sub interpreters for separating what is being run. There are no pure Python WSGI servers that I know of that are run up from Python command line that do this, it being a thing that embedded solutions alone, such as mod_wsgi and uWSGI, which control interpreter creation do.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - at least `twisted.web` supports Virtual Hosts, so does `cherryd` from cherry.py I'm sure that some of the pure python servers listed in http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/servers.html support them too.

Comment: @Kimvais - You aren't understanding the significance of what I am saying. Even though some support the concept of virtual host mapping to different applications, you can't always run multiple distinct instances of a framework/application within the same process space if run in the same interpreter. You could not therefore run two separate Django projects under different virtual hosts using those servers. This is because Django relies on global data for which there can be only be one set per interpreter. The two distinct framework/applications cant share that global state.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - I do understand. What I don't understand is that why did you bring django up. I did say _usually_. OP didn't ask about virtual hosting and did not mention django either.

Comment: @Kimvais Because you said 'running multiple sites on a single server can also be achieved by most if not all of the pure python alternatives' in your comment and you even refer to a URL with VirtualHosts in it. I was just pointing out that such features are of no use if trying to host multiple django sites. So I am reacting to your comment, not your answer or original post.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by reading:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/python-interpreter-is-not-created-for.html

The basic principle of when/how sub interpreters are created and used is the same in mod_wsgi as well.

The question is why you would want to use mod_python as a basis for learning how it works as mod_python is no longer being developed and has been moved to the attic by the Apache software foundation. The mod_wsgi module also fixes various things mod_python gets wrong with thread handling if your intention is to go down to that level.